# Extract data from XML with namespaces

Tags: php, xml, parsing, namespaces, extract

I can't quite get the coding right to extract this one string (hostPIN) from the XML response below.  I've been searching and can't get anything to work.  How can I extract that data using PHP?

I am posting just the path to the data I need to get because the XML data is quite large.

```
<serv:message>
 <serv:body>
  <serv:bodyContent xsi:type="use:getUserResponse">
   <use:personalMeetingRoom>
     <use:hostPIN>1234</use:hostPIN>
```

How do I extract 1234?  The namespaces are confusing and I can't find some code that would work with this.

Comment: You may use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927855/extracting-xml-data-to-php) as example and read your data.

Comment: Can you post a link to your complete xml file? or show the namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a base example with `DOMDocument`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xmlString, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$nsURI = $dom->lookupNameSpaceUri( 'use' );
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagNameNS ( $nsURI , 'hostPIN' ) as $node )
{
    echo $node->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you will load xml from a file/url instead that from a string, use `$dom->load` instead of `$dom->loadXML`.

`$node->nodeValue` is the value that you want.

#### Please note:

In the example above, `$dom->lookupNameSpaceUri( 'use' )` may not work, depending on where the namespace is declared. In this case, you can find by you the namespaceURI (it's declared somewhere in document as `xmlns:use="http://example.com/someurl"`) and replace this line:

```
$nsURI = $dom->lookupNameSpaceUri( 'use' );
```

whit this:

```
$nsURI = "http://example.com/someurl";
```

Comment: I'm not getting an echo.  Let me add more info.  I am sending an XML API using curl and receiving the XML response back.

I'm using $data = curl_exec($ch); at the end which is receiving the response back that I'm trying to parse.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @fusion3k after a few more tweaks I got it to work with

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $data, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$nsURI = "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user";
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagNameNS ( $nsURI , 'hostPIN' ) as $node )
{
   echo $node->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```